# SP2010 custom ranking model filetypes

Tags: 2010, search, xml

I have a custom ranking model which works great. But is it possible to give some page layouts higher ranking than others?

I started trying this with file types as a lot of the examples are using that. But it is not working.

The `rankingmodel.xml` I use looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><rankingModel
name="CustomRankingModel"
id="302A9E0E-F8B9-4b21-8180-C327ECCBBA94"
description="Custom Ranking Model"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2009/rankingModel">
  <queryDependentFeatures>
    <queryDependentFeature name="Body" pid="1" weight="13" lengthNormalization="0.5"/>
    <queryDependentFeature name="Title" pid="2" weight="20" lengthNormalization="0.5"/>
    <queryDependentFeature name="Author" pid="3" weight="8" lengthNormalization="0.5"/>
    <queryDependentFeature name="Description" pid="6" weight="5" lengthNormalization="0.5"/>
    <queryDependentFeature name="FileExtension" pid="319" weight="10" lengthNormalization="0.5"/>
    <queryDependentFeature name="MetaInformatie" pid="403" weight="11" lengthNormalization="0.5"/>
    <queryDependentFeature name="Filename" pid="56" weight="10" lengthNormalization="0.5" />
    <queryDependentFeature name="FileType" pid="98" weight="10" lengthNormalization="0.5" />
  </queryDependentFeatures>
  <queryIndependentFeatures>
    <categoryFeature name="FileType" pid="98" default="0">
      <category name="Aspx" value="0" weight="0" />
      <category name="Docx" value="1" weight="30" />
      <category name="Pdf" value="2" weight="100" />
    </categoryFeature>
  </queryIndependentFeatures>
</rankingModel>
```

I tried in the xml above to show `.pdf` on top and hide or display `.aspx` files below. But I can't seem to give them the right name/value/weight.

Again in the end I want to use it on the content type of the page layout (if it is even possible) but for now I wish I could understand how to modify the file type weights.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't worked with custom ranking since FAST ESP so apologies in advance if I'm not much help.

Sounds like you narrowed it down to name/value/rank for FileType. Here are a few thoughts:

1. Have you confirmed your *FileType* values match what's in your instance?
2. Is *value* OK to begin with 0? (An example in the book referenced below starts with 1.)
3. Are your *category* elements listed in correct order? Maybe order highest to lowest by *value*. (I doubt this is it but SharePoint Search can be very finicky. See [page 412 of Pro SharePoint 2010 Search by Noble, Piddoke, Bakmand-Mikalski](https://books.google.com/books?id=0FD4GGoAKEoC&pg=PA412&lpg=PA412&dq=categoryfeature%20queryindependentfeatures%20name%20value%20weight&source=bl&ots=w3iLA-DJKK&sig=s25WtN_BlkJ0wyEnjZNaRm-iEKU&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwim7sPN_PjMAhVE5WMKHdvwDXYQ6AEINDAE#v=onepage&q=categoryfeature%20queryindependentfeatures%20name%20value%20weight&f=false))
4. Is your Search Web Part set to use the new ranking model? (Since you already have a custom ranking model that works, I suspect this isn't it either, but we all miss a detail eventually. [This post](https://sharepointkaos.wordpress.com/2011/01/13/custom-ranking-model/) provides details.)
5. Are you troubleshooting with the [SharePoint 2013 Search Query Tool](https://sp2013searchtool.codeplex.com/)?

To confirm your FileType values match those in the system, try the below SP commands, gleaned from [blogspot](http://techtrainingnotes.blogspot.com/2015/03/sharepoint-2013-search-file-extensions.html)

```
$ssa = Get-SPEnterpriseSearchServiceApplication
Get-SPEnterpriseSearchFileFormat -SearchApplication $ssa | ft –AutoSize
```

I hope this helps. Please let me know.

Comment: tnx for the answer but i do not have the files/site anymore so i can not  answer your questions. :(